# 1ª se torna 1\u00aa quando insiro no json

Tags: php, json

Quando eu insiro `1ª` no JSON com o codeigniter, quando transformo em string ele vira `1\u00aa`.

```
$t[0]["teste"] = "1ª";
$data[0]["algo"] = $t;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal. O PHP usa o formato `\u quatro-dígitos-hex` para escapar caracteres especiais (não-ASCII). Isso é JSON válido, veja [json.org](http://www.json.org)

Se realmente quiser evitar o escape, pode usar a opção `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`:

```
php > // com a flag:
php > print(json_encode('ºªáéíóú',JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
"ºªáéíóú"

php > // sem a flag:
php > print(json_encode('ºªáéíóú'));
"\u00ba\u00aa\u00e1\u00e9\u00ed\u00f3\u00fa"
```

Comment: E tem alguma forma de salvar como `ª` dentro do JSON, ou ele apenas permite pelo código do carácter ??

Comment: Você já está salvando o `ª`, ele só está sendo representado em hexadecimal. Quando você for consumir o JSON, os valores tipicamente são decodificados. Por exemplo: digite `'\u00aa'` e dê enter no console do DevTools do seu navegador. Será exibido `ª`.

Comment: Tem como mandar um ª diretamente no JSON sim, mas não é recomendado porque você pode ter algum problema na decodificação. O seu framework de web está fazendo a conversão automática para você. Se você gerar o JSON manualmente, poderá colocar o ª nessa forma.

Comment: No caso, eu pego uma string do banco de dados, uso `json_decode`, insiro as informações, e depois uso `json_encode`, e coloco novamente no banco de dados, e lá no banco de dados aparece `\u00aa`, o problema pode estar no banco de dados ??

Comment: Usa json_decode antes de mandar pro banco de dados.

Comment: Como ele está em array, eu uso o `json_encode` para transformar em string para conseguir inserir no banco de dados. Caso eu use `json_decode` em um array ele diz ` json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`, não entendi muito bem oque quis que eu fizesse.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61131/discussion-between-rodorgas-and-lucas-carezia).